# Marginal Likelihood of Multinomial Dirichlet model

Tags: self-study, distributions, likelihood, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

To find the marginal likelihood of the multinomial Dirichlet model, I tried the following:
$$\int_\theta p(N|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta=\frac{n!}{n_1!...n_K!}\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k)}{\Pi_{k=1}^K\Gamma(\alpha_k)}\int_\theta\Pi_{k=1}^K\theta_k^{n_k+\alpha_k-1}d\theta = \frac{n!}{n_1!...n_K!}\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k)}{\Pi_{k=1}^K\Gamma(\alpha_k)}c^{-1}\int_\theta c\space\Pi_{k=1}^K\theta_k^{n_k+\alpha_k-1}d\theta$$
Where a constant $c$ was introduced in the last step. If we let $c=\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k+n_k)}{\Pi_{k=1}^K\Gamma(\alpha_k+n_k)}$, then the integral is the integral of a pdf, hence is equal to $1$. $c^{-1}=\frac{1}{c}$, hence we get 
$$\frac{n!}{n_1!...n_K!}\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k)}{\Pi_{k=1}^K\Gamma(\alpha_k)}\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^K\Gamma(\alpha_k+n_k)}{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^K\alpha_k+n_k)}$$

I thought this was correct, but when I computed the value for an example, and then tried to obtain the same value indirectly, through Monte Carlo approximations, I ended up with a radically different quantity. I feel like I must have made a mistake somewhere, and if someone could point it out to me, that would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Could you describe the Monte Carlo procedure you used?  After all, that could be where the mistake was made!  2. If you work through the binomial case and compare your results with the Beta-binomial distribution, you'll see they match (or so it appears to me) which lends credence to the hypothesis that the error is in the approximation, not the math.

Comment: I took $R$ samples from the prior distribution, then computed $p(N|\theta_r)$ for every sample taken, then computed $\frac{1}{R}\sum_{i=1}^Rp(N|\theta_r)$ and that was my estimation of the marginal likelihood. This is how I was taught to do it, or so I think. Did I make a mistake there? I hope my notation isn't confusing to you. $N$ are the realisations of the RV, $\theta_r$ is one of the R samples.

Comment: You might want to try testing your code with $K=2$, the Beta-binomial case, as well, since you can find the actual distribution on Wikipedia so if the results differ from the actual distribution's values you know that it's a programming error.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thanks. That basically means you think my derivation above is correct, and that the issue is with the coding?

Comment: Such is my belief, but, not surprisingly, I've been wrong before.

Comment: As I lay down in bed, I realised my mistake; I had simply plugged in the wrong numbers in the equation I derived above. Both the approximation and the derivation were correct. With a sample size R=10,000, the value was already extremely close to the value calculated through the formula above. Just thought I should let you know.

Comment: Excellent!  It happens to all of us, now and again...